# Constructing a 2D array by appending rows to an empty array

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

The following code snippet does exactly what I want, i.e. fill a 2D array by appending lists, starting from an empty list of lists. How do I achieve the same using only numpy arrays?

```
import numpy as np
list = []
list.append([1,2,3])
list.append([4,5,6])
array=np.array(list)
```

Comment: stick with that.  Array 'append' is slower and not as easy to do right. The question comes up often.  Learn to use arrays as designed; don't imitate list methods.

Comment: Just a small comment: avoid using `list` as variable name, because it overrides the original `list` type name. If you need to use `list(...)` later on for example, you'll have trouble

Comment: If you know the size of the matrix beforehand, it is much cheaper to preallocate and fill it progressively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `numpy.append` function:

```py
import numpy as np
lst = np.ndarray((0, 3)) # empty matrix with three columns
lst = np.append(lst, [[1, 2, 3]], axis=0) # note the two pairs of brackets
lst = np.append(lst, [[4, 5, 6]], axis=0) # axis is required
```

This gives:

```py
>>> lst
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

There is no way to append values in-place. Each call to `append()` will allocate a new array and copy values over. This will be slower than appending to a list and converting at the end.

Comment: do not recommend this - it is EVIL

Comment: Thanks Emilio. I see the problem now. I tried to numpy.append lists to an empty numpy.array rather than an empty numpy.ndarray.

Comment: @hpaulj, I was replying to the question, as posed. I did add a note saying why it is bad, though.